# print only part of string in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to print only one part of string in column and ignore the remaining stuff including special characters, how can i acheive it

```
| A        | B              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| abc      | zet=kadala;    |
| def      | zet=kade; None |
| de       | zet=kad; None:81 |
```

Tried SUBSTRING_INDEX(B,'=', -1) AS B

expected output

```
| A        | B              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| abc      | kadala         |
| def      | kade           |
| de       | kad            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX() function to extract the required substring from column B. The SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns a substring from a string before or after a specified delimiter.

Here's an example SQL query that should give you the expected output:

```sql
SELECT A, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, '=', -1), ';', 1) AS B
FROM your_table_name;
```

In the above query, we are using two nested SUBSTRING_INDEX() functions to extract the required substring from column B.

The inner SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns the substring after the last occurrence of the '=' character, which gives us 'kadala' in the first row, 'kade' in the second row, and 'kad' in the third row.

The outer SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns the substring before the first occurrence of the ';' character, which removes the remaining characters after 'kadala', 'kade', and 'kad'.

Note: Replace 'your_table_name' with the actual name of your table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` route, then you will need to call it *twice*:

```sql
SELECT A, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, ';', 1), '=', -1) AS B
FROM yourTable;
```

On MySQL 8+, you could also use a regex replacement:

```sql
SELECT A, REGEXP_REPLACE(B, '^.*?=|;.*$', '') AS B
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the substring after the '=' character in column B and remove any additional characters after the semicolon (;), you can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX function twice.

Here's an example SQL query that should achieve the expected output:

```
SELECT A, TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, '=', -1), ';', 1)) AS B
FROM table_name;
```

This query will select column A and a substring of column B that starts after the last occurrence of the '=' character and ends at the first occurrence of the ';' character. The TRIM function is used to remove any leading or trailing spaces from the resulting string.

The output of this query should be a new table with only the desired substring in column B.